# Can't figure out monitoring and "trackedProperties" setting

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Trying to follow along here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-monitor-your-logic-apps

But that is neither a tutorial nor a reference and so is incomplete. I want to have logging which includes custom trackedProperties. Can you please outline all the required steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely.  So first you can define the custom tracked properties you want to track.  Switch to code-view and add the "trackedProperties" object as defined in the article above.  At runtime, all of these tracked properties will be added and emitted in the run telemetry.

After you have specified all of the properties you want to custom track, you need to read or view the diagnostics data.  Currently there are a few ways to do that:

1. On the **Diagnostics** settings for the workflow, you can set **Diagnostics Settings** to export to Azure Storage or Azure Event Hub to process later.
2. Use **Diagnostics Logs** to enable diagnostics and send to **Log Analytics** to be searched and index by OMS.

An example of a diagnostics message can be seen in the article above - you'll notice a "trackedProperties" object in the diagnostic message for the "ActionCompleted" event which will contain any of your custom tracked properties.

Hopefully that helps.  If you want more control over dealing with messages option 1 works (But requires you configure a event processor to see logs) -- the Log Analytics provides more.  Info on log analytics can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-storage)

Comment: Right now the Azure portal is down - at least for me. 

I did start to experiment. I set "Azure Storage" in Diagnostic Settings. And I triggered some successful and some failed operations. But it seems that nothing was added to the log storage. I will look again when the portal comes back up.

Comment: Hi Jeff,
When I click on "Diagnostics logs" under MONITORING, I see a single row with "No results". I assumed that it was here that I would see my logs. Could you elaborate on the use of logs in terms of how to use them?

Comment: Yeah - so if you click Diagnostic logs it looks like that's not correctly rendering the logs - I'll report that to the monitoring team.  My preferred approach is click **Diagnostic Logs** and set Diagnostic Settings to export to Log Analytics.  Then you can use OMS which will automatically injest and index the logs for you.  So if you open your log analytics instance later you could query something like "Type=AzureDiagnostics" and see all the logs - with tracked properties - in OMS.  The storage and event hub should work too - just isn't auto-indexed

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.